# Cursor execution - Python

Tags: django, python-2.7, cursor, mysql-python

I am working on a Django project where i use MySql database. In my project, one of the method used two cursor connections to execute the query. It was closed correctly.

The MySql database has a table called GeometryTable where it had two columns (Geometry Datatypes). One is `GeomPolygon` (Polygon values) and another is `GeomPoint` (Point data). I wrote a MySql query in my python project which  returns the selected points and polygons within the given polygon. The table (GeometryTable) had 9 million rows of values.

When i run the query in MySql Workbench, it took a few seconds. But in project, it took several minutes to return the values. Anyone please help me to optimize the code. Thanks

The method is :

```
def GeometryShapes(polygon): 

    geom = 'POLYGON((' + ','.join(['%s %s' % v for v in polygon]) + '))'    
    query1 = 'SELECT GeomId, AsText(GeomPolygon)' \
            ' FROM GeometryTable' \
            ' WHERE MBRWithin(GeomPolygon, GeomFromText("%s")) AND length(GeomPolygon) < 10 million' % (geom)

    query2 = 'SELECT GeomId, AsText(GeomPoint)' \
                 ' FROM GeometryTable' \
                 ' WHERE  MBRWithin(GeomPoint, GeomFromText("%s")) AND length(GeomPoint) < 10 million' % (geom)  

    if query1:
     cursor = connection.cursor()
     cursor.execute(query1)           
     .....
     cursor.close()
    if query2:         
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      cursor.execute(query2)
      .......
      cursor.close()
```

Here, while cursor execution (`cursor.execute(query1)` and `cursor.execute(query2)`) took several minutes to execute the query. I have indexed both the columns in the specified table.

Can anyone help me to optimize the code?